# Age of civilization Khmer ability

Tags: untagged

The "Khmer" card ability states that "When Khmer rises, +3 Coins per Wonder":

[image: Khmer ability]

It's not clear to me if this means +3 coins for each wonder that *I* own, or is it for each wonder in the *game*, including those owned by other players.

The rulebook does not clarify this.

Comment: You've tagged this "house-rules" - could you clarify what you're looking for here, as your question seems to be referring to what the official ruling is, the exact opposite of a house rule?

Comment: I'm assuming the [tag:house-rules] tag was chosen arbitrarily since there was no proper [tag:age-of-civilization] tag to use. I've created the game tag and removed house rules, but if that was in error go ahead and add it back in.

Comment: No, that was the reason. I was unable to post without a tag. and there was no tag for the game, and no general tag for "rule-clarification".

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the rules [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/57030/age-of-civilization-khmer-ability) There isn't an example for that specific card.  However there is a picture of a card for Arabia[image: Arabia card saying 'per'] which uses the word 'per'

The rules clarification for Arabia says :-

> Whenever YOUR turn end, for every technology you have, you gain 1
> coin.

as 'per' there is referring to cards owned by the player (and not all other players) I see no reason why the Khmer card with 'per' would not also mean just those belonging to the player.

I think if it meant all those in the game the card would say so explicitly as that's not that common in games.   If it was all players the balance of the game would vary on higher player counts meaning a card like that would get you you more.  This also makes me say that the Khmer card is just referring to wonders owned by the one player playing the card.